# I want to run Form1 from program.cs but every time i write Form1 instead of Form5. it gets Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here is the code from Program.cs i am weak in C#. every time i write Form1 instead of Form5 it gives me Error

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form5());
}
```

Comment: The question is extremely broad, any number of things could be the issue here. For starters, make sure `Form1` is declared & implemented correctly, and in the same namespace as Program.cs.

Comment: CS0246 it is error code. i dont know why can i not share the snap with you in comment. it will be much easier for me

Comment: You can add the text of the error to the question, which can be edited at any time

Comment: Please add the text of the error message you are seeing. What is the exact type or namespace that cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create new Form through Solution -> Add -> New Form
**Step 2:** Replace Form5() with name of the new Form

for your case it is possible that Form1 might not Exists in your project try to make sure that Form1 really exists in your project